# page not accessiing data from json file

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi i am new to SharePoint.
I am using SharePoint 2016 online and have admin rights
what i did was I made a simple .aspx page which contains a table which gets data from a json file.
I opened library using file explorer and added these files to site pages after that when i open the page everything is working fine but the table is not getting data from the json.

My table code
The path is data-url="tables/data1.json" the folder tables is also inside site pages folder

```
 <table data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/data1.json"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" >Item ID</th>
                            <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                            <th data-field="name"  data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                            <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

I also read that there are certain files blocked in SharePoint.
I read this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

But in SharePoint 2016 online admin center the security setting where we can check blocked file type is not showing.
What else can i do?